# GRPC code generation generates warnings when client and server code are both built

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, grpc

I get the following warning when I build both the client and the server side grpc files when they both refer to the same .proto file. I am wondering if I should just ignore this warning or if I should take it seriously, as to me it seems like this is more of an intellisense warning than one about the code.

> warning CS0436: The type 'A' in '\obj\Debug\Greet.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'A' in 'GRPCClient, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type defined in '\obj\Debug\Greet.cs'.

Note I changed the actual type to 'A' for the purpose of this question. This problem seems to only occur when I have them both refer to the same .proto file. But this is sort of what I want as I don't want to manage 2 proto files for both server and client which would be identical.

Comment: I would expect it to generate a single file with both client and server parts in. It's not clear to me exactly what you're doing. Please could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: it *sounds* like maybe you are generating the same types (from the same proto files) twice in the same system, but where two of those parts are involved in a reference way - possibly giving an ambiguous type

Comment: I made an example repository for https://github.com/Belpaire/GRPCminimalExample, it seems that once you have a projectreference it will start behaving like this. I am indeed guessing that having a reference (or a dependency somewhere later down the line) where the client code is, is what is causing this issue. When I was receiving the warning I didn't see any strange behaviour, but I am not convinced if it is truly safe to ignore this warning.

Comment: I am guessing the way to solve it would thus be to make it so that there is no dependencypath from the server to the client grpc project, so that part of the question is sort of solved. I am guessing the warning is of the kind of "might work now, and break down when the implementation invariably changes slightly", although maybe someone that is more familiar might be able to say this for sure.

Answer (score -1):

So Marc Gravell was right in that when you have a client/server proto project, you should not have projectreferences (direct or indirect) to it. So to solve these warnings all you need to do is make sure there is no path from the server project to the client project.